# Minimise delay between Salesforce Streaming API and Heroku Connect

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, salesforce, heroku-connect

I currently have an app (node.js) running in Heroku, using Heroku Connect to connect to Salesforce to read/write data.

Heroku Connect essentially has a copy of selected data from Salesforce, which is pulled in via the Streaming API.

My application instantly writes to the HC PostgreSQL database, which instantly writes up to Salesforce.

This adds a unique reference field that is also instantly generated in Salesforce, however there is delay in this information being fed back to Heroku Connect.

I'm not sure if the delay is because of the streaming API or Heroku Connect, but I'm not sure how to minimise/remove this delay so that Heroku Connect instantly updates with the newly generated field.

Please take a look at the diagram below showing what is instant and where the delay is happening:

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Outbound streaming in Salesforce is asynchronous... That mean delay is something normal. Please read "[Integration Patterns and Practices](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf)" for more details. I'm not sure which of the strategies they describes fits your needs, but at least you have kind of reference. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the cause of such delays could be socket & reconnect timeouts (read more about Streaming API timeouts [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_timeouts.htm)). If your Salesforce side of solution generate events not pretty often the client can lose connection and need to reconnect each time and there is can be wasting of time which you observe. Possible, solution for such case is to generate fake events on Salesforce side (without real data) for keeping alive connection, but you need to care about reaching another Streaming API limitations (for instance, amount of events within a 24–hour period). For more details about limits see [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_streaming_api.htm).

It's just an idea and you need to make some benchmark tests and collect some statistics for better understanding how exactly Salesforce & Heroku Connect interact in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In Heroku Connect you can enable Accelerated Polling on any mapping and minimize the polling to 2 minutes. It’s not possible to set polling to Instant.  In fact, the diagram above is inaccurate in that sense: the write from Heroku Connect to Salesforce is never Instant.